# How can I set a constraint before plotting some curve (pgfplot)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to set some constraint for a predefined function (see code below) before the plotting, to avoid changes on the functions.

The constraint must be #6+#7=constant, so I can choose the constant.

As you can see on the code, my attempt to solve this was writing 'x' for the parameter #6 and '50-x' for #7. But I don't know if this is the right and the only way one can set this constraint without making any modifications on the \def functions. 
(Sorry for the bad english)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,physics,amssymb,mathtools,upgreek,bm}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13,translate gnuplot=true}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{scalerel,relsize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Definindo a Função IC50 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\g(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){(#6)*exp(-(#2))+((#6)**2)*exp(2*(-(#2)))*(#9)*exp((#4))}%

\def\f(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){1+2*(#6)*exp(-(#2))+((#6)**2)*exp(2*(-(#2)))*exp((#4))}%

\def\h(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){2*(#7)*exp(-(#1)) +exp( (#3) )*( (#7)*exp(-(#1) ) )^2 + 2*(#6)*exp(-(#2))*(#7)*exp(-(#1) )*exp((#5)) }%

\def\v(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){( \g(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) + (#6)*exp(-(#2))*(#7)*exp(-(#1))*(#8)*exp((#5)) )/( \f(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) + \h(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) )}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
            tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
        label style={font=\scriptsize},            
            xlabel=${[S](\upmu M)}$ / ${[H_2O]}$,           
            ylabel=${ ({d[P]}/{dt})(2K_{cat}[E_{tot}])^{-1}}$,      
            legend pos=north east,
            grid=major,        
            ymax=1, ymin=0,
            xmax=50, xmin=1,
            x dir=reverse,  
            ] 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 \addplot[red,mark=none,domain=0.0001:200,samples=250, line width=1]
  gnuplot { \v((-12),(-12),0,0,0,x/10^6,(50-x)/10^6,1,1) };
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mathematically it is correct and of course the choice is not unique. Just to give you an example, if you have the constraint `x^2+y^2=1`, you could either do `y=sqrt(1-x^2)` or `x=cos(t),y=sin(t)` or `x=sin(t),y=cos(t)` and so on.

Comment: I know that mathematically it is correct, but I just wasn't sure how the pgfplots package would see what I've wrote.

Comment: Never ever do things like `\def\g` or for any other single letter macro name. You have no idea at all what you are overwriting, if anything. You do no checks to make sure. And you are (re)defining these macro names **globally**. In this case, you're fairly lucky: 3 of your 4 macro names are undefined, at least by TeX (I didn't check LaTeX). But you may need the remaining 1 or one of the packages you use may use it. And, as I say, I didn't check LaTeX.

Comment: You might consider using \pgfmathdeclarefunction (page 942). I'm not sure it would be any faster, but pgfplots might like it better.  Also, please square number using x*x instead of x^2 or x**2.

Comment: I will give it a try, John. Thx for the help!